# problem making a led bink in oled1xplainnedpro using a atmega324pbxplainnedpro

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, led

without calling the delay() function the led turns on but it doesnt when i do
other leds on the oled1 can blink with this function
the led on the main board works too but the one on the io1xplainnedpro has the same problem
the only difference between the code that works and the one that doesnt is the calling of the delays() function

```
#define LED0 7
#define LED1 5
#define LED2 4
#define LED3 3
#define LED_IO1 3

void delays(void){
  int delay = 1600000;/*a long integeger that will make the loop longer, cant put higher number so we make a lot of integers*/
  int delay1 = 1600000;
  int delay2 = 1600000;
  int delay3 = 1600000;
  int delay4 = 1600000;
  int delay5 = 1600000;
  int delay6 = 1600000;
  int delay7 = 1600000;
  int delay8 = 1600000;
  int delay9 = 1600000;
  int delay10 = 1600000;
  int delay11 = 1600000;
  
  int delay12 = 1600000;
  int delay13 = 1600000;
  int delay14 = 1600000;
  int delay15 = 1600000;
  int delay16 = 1600000;
  int delay17 = 1600000;
  int delay18 = 1600000;
  int delay19 = 1600000;
  int delay20 = 1600000;
  int delay21 = 1600000;
  int delay22 = 1600000;
  int delay23 = 1600000;
  
  
  
 
  int i = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  
  while(i < delay && i < delay1 && i < delay2 && i < delay3 && i < delay4 && i < delay5 && i < delay6 && i < delay7 && i < delay8 && i < delay9 && i < delay10 && i < delay11 && i < delay12 && i < delay13 && i < delay14 && i < delay15 && i < delay16 && i < delay17 && i < delay17 && i < delay18 && i < delay19 && i < delay20 && i < delay21 && i < delay22 && i < delay23){
    /*a loop that will go through all the integers to compare them to i*/
    i++;
    x = i;
    x = y;
    x = z;/*make the loop do something to make the loop last longer*/
  
  }
}

void delay1s(void){
  /*its complicated to keep adding more integers in the loop so we call the last function twice and put in a function to be called inside the main to have a more clear code*/
  delays();
  delays();
}



int main(void) {
    // Set led1 as output
    
    // Set led1, LED2, LED3 AND LED_IO1 as output
    DDRD |= (1 << LED1);
    /*DDRD |= (1 << LED2);
    DDRA |= (1 << LED3);
    DDRB |= (1 << LED_IO1);*/
    

    while (1) {
        // Turn on LED1 by driving led1 low
        
        // Turn on LED1, LED2, LED3 AND LED_IO1 by driving PIN low
        PORTD &= ~(1 << LED1);
        delays();
        PORTD |= (1 << LED1);
        delays();
        /*PORTD &= ~(1 << LED2);
        PORTA &= ~(1 << LED3);
        PORTB &= ~(1 << LED_IO1);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: first off that delays function should be dead code and get optimized out.   you want to make the count longer and cant make the int bigger (why cant you make the int bigger, how big is it on this compiler?  then you nest loops, using your syntax a while in a while. is your delay too long and you cant see the led for that reason?  unless you wait?

Comment: I dont remember if you can count instructions (relative to clocks) for avr to then use a count loop for accurate timing (like you can with a pic) but this is C code yes so even there not necessarily the best way for an accurately timed loop (if delay1s implies one second).  perfectly good way to start a blinker program, preferred way, to use a count loop, then...use a timer if you want to get to a second or something (and you may need to loop around the timer to get N timeouts to get to a big number like one second).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the AVR is an 8-bit MCU. In this case, the type int is usually 2 bytes long, so the maximum value that can be stored is 32767. If you assign the value 1600000 to the `delay` variable, the C compiler will do an implicit type conversion from long to int and the result will be 27136 (and issue warnning). But this is very a small number of cycles in your while loop. Adding additional `delayxx` variables has no effect on the number of cycles. Only time of evaluation the condition is extended.

Here's how to fix the `delays` function:

```
void delays(void){
  long int delay = 1600000;
  long int i=0;
  while(i < delay){
    i++;
  }
}
```

Or you can use shorted version

```
void delays(void){
  long int i=1600000; //of course value need trimm
  while(i--);
}
```

Don't ignore any C compiler warnning.